# Constantly get an error "no such table" whatever I do

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, model

I am pretty new to django and database management as well, therefore there is certainly a possibility that I do not understand some crucial things about them.

I've been trying to solve this error by myriads of ways for a few days **(*It occured as a result of a declaration of a new field in existing model called Habit*)**, I tried:

- resetting database with reset_db (django-extensions)
- flushing it with native django flush command (now I do understand
  that it was a wrong method)
- recreating a whole app in another virtual environment with creation
  of fresh databases
- faking migrations with --fake (out of desperation basically)
- manually changing fields in a db with sql browser
- deleting sqlite database manually and making migrations

***Here are my models:***

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime

# Create your models here.

class Day(models.Model): # Creating table for this model didn't cause any trouble 
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)

class Habit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    targ_init_time = models.TimeField(auto_created=False, auto_now_add=False, default=datetime.time())
    targ_term_time = models.TimeField(auto_created=False, auto_now_add=False, default=datetime.time())

    true_init_time = models.TimeField(auto_created=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, default=datetime.time())
    true_term_time = models.TimeField(auto_created=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, default=datetime.time())

    is_completed =  models.BooleanField(default=False)

    day = models.ForeignKey(Day, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='habits') # --That New Field I've added--
    
    def find_duration(self):
        total_targ_time = timedelta(hours=self.targ_term_time.hour, minutes=self.targ_term_time.minute) - timedelta(hours=self.targ_init_time.hour, minutes=self.targ_init_time.minute)
        total_true_time = timedelta(hours=self.true_term_time.hour, minutes=self.true_term_time.minute) - timedelta(hours=self.true_init_time.hour, minutes=self.true_init_time.minute)

        return [total_true_time, total_targ_time]

    def format_time(self):
        time = self.find_duration()

        true = float(".".join(str(time[0]).split(":"))[0:4])
        targ = float(".".join(str(time[1]).split(":"))[0:4])

        if true < 1:
            true = str(int(true * 100)) + ' mins'
        else:
            true = str(true) + ' hours'

        if targ < 1:
            targ = str(int(targ * 100)) + ' mins'
        else:
            targ = str(targ) + ' hours' 
        
        return [true, targ]

    def find_productivity(self):
        total_both_time = self.find_duration()

        try:
            productivity = int(total_both_time[0] / total_both_time[1] * 100)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            productivity=0

        return productivity

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

***Views:***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.template import loader

from datetime import timedelta, time

from .models import Habit
from .forms import HabitForm, EditHabitForm

# Create your views here.
def dayViewHabitIndex(request):
    all_habits = Habit.objects.all()
    form = HabitForm()
    template = loader.get_template("Tracker/one_day_habits.html")

    productivity_list = [habit.find_productivity() for habit in all_habits]

    try:
        median_productivity = int(sum(productivity_list) / len(productivity_list))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        median_productivity = 0

    context = {'habits_list':all_habits, 'median_productivity':median_productivity, 'form':form}

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def addHabit(request):
    new_habit = HabitForm(request.POST)
    if new_habit.is_valid():
        new_habit.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Tracker:index'))

def editHabitsTime(request, habit_id):
    certain_habit = Habit.objects.get(id=habit_id)
    template = loader.get_template('Tracker/editHabitsTime.html')
    form = EditHabitForm()

    context = {'certain_habit':certain_habit, 'form':form}

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def editSuccess(request, habit_id, template='Tracker/editHabitsTime.html'):
    changes = EditHabitForm(request.POST, instance=Habit.objects.get(id=habit_id))
    if changes.is_valid():
        changes.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Tracker:index'))
    
    else:
        return render(request, template, {'form':form, 'warning':'Something Went Wrong'})
```

***App urls:***

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'Tracker'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.dayViewHabitIndex, name='index'),
    path('createHabit/', views.addHabit, name='addHabit'),
    path('<int:habit_id>/edit/', views.editHabitsTime, name='editHabit'),
    path('<int:habit_id>/success/>', views.editSuccess, name='saveChanges'),
]
```

***Forms***:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.forms.fields import DateField
from django import forms

from . import models

HABIT_NAMES = zip([habit.name for habit in models.Habit.objects.all()], [habit.name for habit in models.Habit.objects.all()]) 

class HabitForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Habit
        #widgets = {'name': forms.Select(choices=HABIT_NAMES)}
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {'name': _(''), 'targ_init_time':_(''), 'targ_term_time':_(''), 'true_init_time':_(''), 'true_term_time':_(''), 'is_completed':_('') }
    
class EditHabitForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Habit
        exclude = ('name', 'targ_init_time', 'targ_term_time', )
```

***Full Error Message:***

```
(WebApp-G_WmOMr9) D:\CodingPython\New_Folder_For_Great_And_Strucrurised_Work\WebApp>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Tracker_habit

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 368, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\CodingPython\New_Folder_For_Great_And_Strucrurised_Work\WebApp\HabitTracker\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('', include('Tracker.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\CodingPython\New_Folder_For_Great_And_Strucrurised_Work\WebApp\Tracker\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "D:\CodingPython\New_Folder_For_Great_And_Strucrurised_Work\WebApp\Tracker\views.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .forms import HabitForm, EditHabitForm
  File "D:\CodingPython\New_Folder_For_Great_And_Strucrurised_Work\WebApp\Tracker\forms.py", line 8, in <module>
    HABIT_NAMES = zip([habit.name for habit in models.Habit.objects.all()], [habit.name for habit in models.Habit.objects.all()])
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 287, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1308, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\WebApp-G_WmOMr9\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 413, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: Tracker_habit
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these queries in your forms are executed and cause the error even before your "makemigrations" is doing the actual makemigrations:

```
HABIT_NAMES = zip([habit.name for habit in models.Habit.objects.all()], [habit.name for habit in models.Habit.objects.all()])
```

I would comment it out and try again.

Comment: I thank you wholeheartedly! It would have taken me days to figure this out if not your help. Thank you Razenstein!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the following command?

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

According to [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#migrate)

> --run-syncdb¶
>
> Allows creating tables for apps without migrations. While this isn’t
> recommended, the migrations framework is sometimes too slow on large
> projects with hundreds of models.